# How to change the speed of an object in Phaser without changing its direction

Tags: javascript, performance, phaser-framework

How do you change the speed of an object in phaser without changing its direction?  For example, I have a ball that collides against a moving platform.  I want the ball to change direction, but not gain any additional speed from the collision against a moving side of the platform. Up to now I have had to take the sign of the velocities of the object and then reapply a constant value speed to it on collision, but that seems quite wrong for a library as robust as Phaser is.

How do you modify speed and direction independently outside of velocity?

Comment: Up to now I've just modified the velocity separately.  For example, I would take the `Math.sign(object.body.velocity.x)` and then assign the speed manually to that while reassigning the direction (`sign`).  While it works, it seems that there should be a more direct way to modify just speed of the direction vectors without these extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `bounce` to get that sort of effect in my games.
Try using `ball.body.bounce.set(1);`.

From the [docs](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#bounce):

> The elasticitiy of the Body when colliding. bounce.x/y = 1 means full
>   rebound, bounce.x/y = 0.5 means 50% rebound velocity.